# Can i write my own metric for image registration in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I try to register two images using Matlab's imregister. i see that i can provide only two metric classes - MeanSquares and MattesMutualInformation.

Is there any possibility to create my own metric class and pass it instead?

Thanks

Comment: Its not that easy. Likely the metrics are used to guide the optimizer, not just as an evaluation step, but as a gradient/direction step. If it uses a gradient based approach, not all metrics can be used, as not all are differenciable, or generate a convex problem. If you want our own metric, you need to write your own minimizer to solve the registration problem

Comment: First of all thanks. Second, well yes - i am willing to do that where and how is it possible?

Comment: If you were to do that you'd need to do your maths on paper, make sure you pose a convex minimization problem and then write whichever maths you proposed as code, using basic functions. No magic here, just hard work